# Access Imported QML Component ID from Imported JS

Tags: import, qml, scope

I'm trying to access an included QML id through an included JavaScript function. And I get the error:

```
Reference error: textItem is not defined.
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import "functions.js" as Logic

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent;
    Button { }
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: Logic.changeText()
    }
}
```

Button.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle  {
    width: 100; height: 30
    color: "black"

    Text  {
        id: textItem
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pointSize: 20
        color: "white"
        text: "Hello!"
    }

}
```

functions.js

```
function changeText() {
    textItem.text = "Goodbye!";
}
```

Is there any way to access an Imported QML's id scope from an imported JS file?

Comment: Sure, textItem is not visible due to scope visible. Pass item id to JS function or someting like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As folibis said, `textItem` is not accessible to `functions.js`. There are more problems with your code, though. The button whose text you want to change has no ID, so you can't change its text even if you wanted to.

Give the button an ID, and then pass the button to `changeText()`:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import "functions.js" as Logic

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent;
    Button {
        id: button
    }
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: Logic.changeText(button)
    }
}
```

The next problem is that your `Button` type doesn't expose a text property. You should make an alias to the text property of `textItem`:

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle  {
    width: 100; height: 30
    color: "black"

    property alias text: textItem.text

    Text  {
        id: textItem
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pointSize: 20
        color: "white"
        text: "Hello!"
    }

}
```

Then the rest will work:

```
function changeText(button) {
    button.text = "Goodbye!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference something from other files (or inside the QML file), you need to think in terms of the QML tree (navigating through the tree with **id** property). With that being said, I would suggest the following changes:

> ```
> import QtQuick 2.1
> import "functions.js" as Logic
>
> Rectangle {
>     id: rootRec
>     anchors.fill: parent;
>     Button {id: myButton}
>     MouseArea {
>         onClicked: Logic.changeText(myButton)
>     }
> }
> ```

In Button.qml:

> ```
> import QtQuick 2.1
> Rectangle  {
>     id: rootRec
>     width: 100; height: 30
>     color: "black"
>     property string text: "Hello"
>
>     Text  {
>         id: textItem
>         anchors.centerIn: parent
>         font.pointSize: 20
>         color: "white"
>         text: rootRec.text
>     }
> }
> ```

In "function.js" you reference it like this:

> function changeText(buttonId) {
>       buttonId.text = "Goodbye!"; }